# Is the correct spelling “fulfil” or “fulfill”?

Tags: american-english, spelling, orthography

Which of the spelling is correct? “fulfil” or “fulfill”? I can find both spellings on the web, although “fulfil” is more common.

Comment: Try checking a dictionary.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Some dictionaries say “fulfil” is a variant of “fulfill” and some say “fulfill” is a variant of “fulfil”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fulfil** is the spelling commonly used in countries which use British English such as the UK, Australia, New Zealand, etc. **Fulfill** is the spelling commonly used in the United States. In Canada, Grammarly says, they use both spellings.

[Fulfil or fulfill](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/fulfil-fulfill/)

Comment: In point of fact, all countries *can* use both spellings. (The variants exist in the dictionaries.)  It's just that one is generally more stylistically acceptable, and should normally be the one used—most people would mark the variant as wrong. In Canada, it's **fulfill** that's the preferred spelling. (Per the *Canadian Oxford Dictionary*.) However, unlike the UK and the US, people and companies in Canada would be much more accepting of the variant being used.